# Density function of $Y - Z$ if $Y,Z$ are exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $Y,Z \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$. How do I work out the p.d.f of $Y-Z$?

I have a feeling I need to do something like this but not sure how to do the integration:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y-Z \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y, Z \leq y-x)$$
$$=\int_{0}^{y} \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\int_{0}^{y-x} \lambda e^{-\lambda t \>}\mathrm{dt \> ds}$$

or something to that effect, but how do I actually work this out?

Is there a nicer way to do it? I tried using moment generating functions but that didn't work out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_X,f_Y,f_Z$ be the pdf of $X=Y-Z, Y$ and $Z$ respectively.

Obviously $f_X$ is symmetric around zero, and for any $x\geq 0$:

$$ f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_Y(x+u)\,f_Z(u)\,du = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda u} e^{-\lambda(x+u)}\,du =e^{-\lambda x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda^2 e^{-2\lambda u}\,du$$
so:
$$ f_X(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2} e^{-\lambda|x|} $$
giving that $Y-Z$ has a [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) $L\left(0,\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)$.